# Custom deck of card in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

How to create this card grid inside container(Bootstrap 4)?
I doesn't understand how i can put text in container if text in div(card).

```html
<section class="second__offers">
    <div class="container">
              <div class="card-group">
            <div class="card text-black">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/service-1.jpg" alt="Card image top">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Card title</h3>
                    <h4 class="card-subtitle">Card subtitle</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a simple Card example</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary service-btn">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-black">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/service-2.jpg" alt="Card image top">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Card title</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a simple Card example</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary service-btn">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-black">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/service-3.jpg" alt="Card image top">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Card title</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a simple Card example</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary service-btn">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    <div class="card-group">
        ...
     </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

example: [image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Click the bracket button: `<>` then post HTML, CSS, and JS/jQ within the Snippet Editor.

Comment: You don't understand how to have the word "service" in a container with the 6 pictures, or you don't understand how to put the text on each of the pictures?

Comment: use background-umage instead image

Comment: @MicahJ yes i can't put text on each pictures and put in container.

Comment: @לבנימלכה but how i put in container for align with other upper elements of the site?

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-image:` instead of `img` tag (add class to each card and in css and the fit `background-image:`)

**To your comment make `container` take `100%` of `width` use `container-fluid` instead of `container` and set in css:**

```
.container-fluid{
  padding:0!important;
  margin:0!important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nhybo32s/10/

```css
.face{
     background-image: url(https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.body{
     background-image: url(https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.card {border:none!important}
.container-fluid{
  padding:0!important;
  margin:0!important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="second__offers">
    <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="card-group">
            <div class="card text-black face">
                <div class="">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Card title</h3>
                    <h4 class="card-subtitle">Card subtitle</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a simple Card example</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary service-btn">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-black body">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="card-title">Card title</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a simple Card example</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary service-btn">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-black">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="card-title">Card title</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a simple Card example</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary service-btn">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    <div class="card-group">
        ...
     </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to fill the empty edges as in the picture above?

Comment: use `.card {border:none}`

Comment: I think you will have to use `!important` to prevent override `.card {border:none!important}`

Comment: you did not understand me a little, sorry for my bad english.Look at the image via link https://imgur.com/lhb6S3r

Comment: you mean you want width of container to be all page width(100%)??

Comment: text stay in container, but card deck full width(100%) - it's all what i want.

Comment: try to use `margin:0` and `padding:0` to `.container `

Comment: margin0 and padding:0 breaks Bootstraps container, i need just set card images full width https://imgur.com/Ns2AjNM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174582/discussion-between-user4478196-and--).

Comment: do you have any ideas? text stay in container(same paddings and margins), card deck full width(100%)

Comment: @לבני מלכה Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568601/how-can-i-add-link-in-the-card-deck-groups